# Service for priority transactions

Tags: mining

I am looking to broadcast a sequence of transactions and hoping these transactions would be mined within the same block. Is there any service that gives preferred access to miners or mining pools and allows you to do time critical transactions?

Use cases would include e.g.

- Not wanting to disclose transactions in mempool, instead the tx would be directly mined from a private mempool
- Frontrunning

Comment: What would you give as incentive if not gas price? Now that I think of this a bit: why not pack your wanted transactions inside one tx which you send to a contract which unpacks and decides to which addresses with what parameters you want the transactions. You'd lose `msg.sender` information, if that's important.

Comment: In this case, transacters are happy to pat $5000 per transaction or so. These are high-value transactions and the privacy, speed and ordering of transactions matters more.

Answer (score 1):

### SecureRPC

SecureRPC provides trade optimization and execution services that improve transaction settlement, improves inclusion rate and speed without adding gas costs.

If you are still looking for such a service, we are beta testing a solution that can facilitate your requirements. In-block positioning (top or bottom), 2-block transaction sets, and of course the normal MEV protection features are being used currently. We have direct connectivity to specific mining pools as well, this ensures total pre-execution privacy and reduces chances of uncle inclusion of your transaction.

Contact me:

- Email: sam [at] manifoldfinance.com
- Telegram: @sambacha

You can find out more via
https://docs.openmev.org
https://docs.sushirelay.com/#introduction

A publicly accessible HTTPS/WebSocket endpoint is available at:

> NOTE. This does not have features that are described above, only offers MEV protection!

- https://api.sushirelay.com/v1
- wss://api.sushirelay.com/v1